# Entity Framework - explain my code

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, updatemodel

Is this a correct understanding of what this code does - and is it the correct way to update a row which has a `URLPath` of `url` so that the `IsInProcessing` column is `true`?

I haven't actually tried this code yet. Before I do, I want to try and understand it! It is pieced together from various sources.

**The code:**

```
using(var db = new DamoclesEntities())
{
    var urls = db.URLS;
    var result = urls.FirstOrDefault(u => u.URLPath == url);
    result.IsInProcessingQueue = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

1. What I think is happening here is within the using I am instantiating the `DamoclesEntities()` class as `var db`.
2. I then instantiate the `db.URLS` (class / table) to the `var urls`.
3. I then find the first row where  the `URLPath` (column) contains `url`, and that row is assigned to `result`.
4. I change that row's `IsInProcessingQueue` (column value) to `true`;
5. Finally, I save the changes to the database.

Comment: Code should work and you understand it correctly, however it could done more elegantly and using std naming conventions.

Comment: You’re understanding is mostly correct. The `using` makes sure that the database is correctly closed, and *assigning* `db.URLS` to a new variable does not instantiate it. Other than that, you got what happens. I still would recommend you to read a book or something though.

Comment: It might also fall over if the URL isn't found: in that case you'll get result = null and a null pointer exception. Is that ever likely to happen? You can change FirstOrDefault to First but that'll just throw a different exception if it doesn't exist. What behaviour do you want in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is almost correct, but keep in mind, that FirstOrDefault will return null value in case if there is no rows found by specified criteria - `URLPath == url`.

So in this case next row will produce NullReferenceException.

Just add check of `result` for a null and do `result.IsInProcessingQueue = true;db.SaveChanges();` only if `result != null`

Comment: "It is almost correct" - can you elaborate on that? What's not correct? Just the NPE?

Comment: What's not correct - 'using' is not just "instantiating", it's kinda shortcut to the construction, that calls Dispose() method of 'db' instance. And not null checking of course.

Comment: You can read about `using` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). Read remarks carefully.